# Azure B2C Active Directory OpenIDConnect and Authorization Codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

I've set up my web app using OpenIDConnectAuthentication as follows. The `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` notification uses Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.13.8.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        MetadataAddress = Settings.AADB2CAuth.SignInPolicyMetaAddress, // https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy} policy = B2C_1_SignIn
        AuthenticationType = Settings.AADB2CAuth.SignInPolicyId, // B2C_1_SignIn

        ClientId = Settings.AADB2CAuth.ClientId, // {guid}

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived 
        },

        RedirectUri = Settings.AADB2CAuth.RedirectUri,

        Scope = "openid",
        ResponseType = "id_token",
    });

private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
{
    var code = context.Code;
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(Settings.AADB2CAuth.ClientId, Settings.AADB2CAuth.ClientSecret);
    string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(Settings.ClaimTypes.ObjectIdentifier).Value;

    string authority = Settings.AADB2CAuth.Authority; // https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}

    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new ADAL.ADALTokenCache(userObjectID));

    Uri redirectUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

    AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, redirectUri, clientCredential, Settings.AADGraphApi.GraphResourceId);
}
```

This works fine. However an authorization code is not returned with the `id_token`. If change this to `code id_token` or just `code`, the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` notification fires, but then I am met with the error

> AADSTS70000: Authentication failed: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid

Basically what I'm trying to do is access the B2C AD as the current signed in user. Is this at all possible?

---

I updated my Authentication Options to

```
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = Settings.AADB2CAuth.SignInPolicyId,
    Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}", Settings.AADB2CAuth.Tenant, Settings.AADB2CAuth.SignInPolicyId),
    ClientId = Settings.AADB2CAuth.ClientId,

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
    },

    RedirectUri = Settings.AADB2CAuth.RedirectUri,

    Scope = "openid",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
});

private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
{
    var code = context.Code;
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(Settings.AADB2CAuth.ClientId, Settings.AADB2CAuth.ClientSecret);
    string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(Settings.ClaimTypes.ObjectIdentifier).Value;
    string authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}", Settings.AADB2CAuth.Tenant, Settings.AADB2CAuth.SignInPolicyId);
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new ADAL.ADALTokenCache(userObjectID));

    Uri redirectUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

    AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, redirectUri, clientCredential, Settings.AADGraphApi.GraphResourceId);
}
```

I am now met with an exception whose details are the HTML content of a 404 page. Looking at the requests I believe it is because `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` is looking at `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/oauth2/token` to send the authorization code to, which I don't think it should?

---

It may be worth noting that the Authorization Code header I get back is the following:

```
{
  "kid": "cpimcore_09252015",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

A quick google search for this yields [one result](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/e07fe6c8-18fe-4b1e-bee1-7280f4d351bc/azure-ad-b2c-how-to-get-the-access-token-and-refresh-token-using-nodejs?forum=WindowsAzureAD) and this references the [following issue](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-NativeClient-Android/issues/1) on the Android ADAL. I'm not sure if this relates to my issue however.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the beginning of this error:

> AADSTSXXXXX

means that when you tried to exchange your auth code, you went to the AAD sts rather than the expected B2C sts:

> AADB2CXXXXX

This means your auth code post request was interpreted incorrectly by our endpoint.  This is *usually* caused when the **policy (p=B2C_1_xxxx)** param for B2C gets appended onto the post URL rather than inside the request.

**Option 1:**
Refactor your code and library usage to stick the policy param inside the auth code post request rather than the end of the token endpoint URL.

**Option 2:**
Use the alternate token endpoint and don't tack on any poliy param. Your new endpoint would look like this

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/B2C_1_myB2CPolicy/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` to exchange the auth code (see updated question). I am not sure it's possible to modify it so that the policy is sent in the body of the request. I tried with the alternate url you supplied, but this did not work either. I'm clearly doing something drastically wrongly.

Comment: That library (ADAL) is meant for what Azure AD calls "v1 apps".  Technically, B2C apps are considered "v2 apps" or "converged apps" (notice inside the URL there's a `/v2.0`). There is a new library for v2 apps called [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet).  Here is a [sample using MSAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2).

Comment: @Mardoxx can you confirm this was the issue?